# Why was I given the Constituent and Caucus badges when I haven't even visited the election page yet?

Tags: support, badges, election

I received 2 of each of the voting badges constituent and caucus.

Not bad considering I haven't voted yet or visited the voting site.

Is this right?

Comment: Also not during the previous elections?

Comment: Ah ok yep I voted in previous elections. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Your Constitutent badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1974/constituent?userid=154186) and [your Caucus badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1973/caucus?userid=154186) link to `election/1` and `election/2`. You haven't been awarded a badge for the current `election/3` yet. You can simply click the "election" link in each badge's description to find out how you earned it.

[image: what the constituent badge description looks like on the badges page]

The badges were [awarded retroactively](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/election-participation-badges/) when they were added:

> Both of these can be earned once for every election. Over the next day we’ll be awarding them retroactively across the network for participation in past elections; participants in current and future elections will see them within minutes of visiting / voting.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.